# How can I get the path followed in J48 decision tree for an instance?

Tags: weka, decision-tree

I would like to know which path in the DT is followed to classify a certain instance. Is there a way to do that (of course without finding it manually in printed or visualized tree)? I am using the java API.

Also what is the best way to visualize a tree?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that Weka provides a way of getting the specific path for an instance. The best way to visualize depends entirely on your requirements, but something like [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) might be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

try JMP from SAS Institute (jmp.com); you can download a trial copy and build the tree for yourself; visualize the paths and also control the branches of the tree; different set breakpoints, etc..